# Java check if data exists on DB

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I have a rest web service with calls in post (i want to write a new entity on the DB) like this:

http://localhost:8080/rest/accounts/id_account/order

and the controller method is this one:

```
@POST
@Path("/{accountid}/orders")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response addOrder(
        @Valid Order order,
        @NotBlank @PathParam("accountid") String accountId);
```

This method should write a new order in the DB.

Everything is simple but I want to check if the entity account with id = id_account exists in the DB, using annotation.

I cannot use a simple validator because is not transactional, so i cannot be sure that the entity account exists when I perform the request.

Is there a way to write a transactional annotation or something similar?

I'm using spring mvc and Jaxrs.

Thanks!

Comment: To make it clear, you are not talking about the _new order's id_, but whether an existing account is found, to add a new order to? A new order id would have been something to return from the database in the response.

Comment: What do you want to do when the account id exist ? Why do you need it to be through annotations ?

Comment: I would like to find a method (the annotations are only an example) to check not just the semantics of the input data. I'll try to explain me with an example. With an annotation I can check if the account id is null or not, I need it so I have put @NotBlank annotation on the field, that's fine, the account id is ok, it is not blank, but I don't know if that exists on my DB or not.

Comment: @Joop you are right. I'm talking about the account id (not the new order). The order is an account's subresource, so I can insert the order only if the account exists on the DB (so the 'select * from accounts where id = account_id' has a result)